# Spring Security: Getting error "The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it"

Tags: spring-security, web.xml

While running the application using Spring Security, I am getting below error on all browsers:

> "The server understood the request but refuses to authorize it"

I tried by changing Roles from "ROLE_ADMIN" to "ROLE_USER" in "spring-security.xml" file.

Below is "spring-security.xml"

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern ="/admin" access = "hasRole('ROLE-USER')"/>
    </http>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name = "abc" password = "xyz" authorities="hasRole('ROLE-USER')" />
        </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Below is SpringController Class:

```
@Controller
public class SpringController {



@RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String homePage() {
        return "HomePage";
    }
    @RequestMapping(value="/admin", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login";
}
```

HomePage.jsp and login.jsp pages are loaded property but after passing credentials on login.jsp getting error:

> HTTP Status 403 – Forbidden
>
> ---
>
> Type: Status Report
>
> Message: Access is denied
>
> Description: The server understood the request but refuses to
>   authorize it.
>
> ---
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.90

Answer (score 0):

403 is a very generic error code. I was facing the same issue but after making some changes I am able to make it work. Still not sure if the problem was with password encryption or configuration of *form-login* tag.

```
<security:http auto-config="true"  >
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*" access="isAnonymous()" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login-user" authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true" />
        <security:logout logout-success-url="/"  />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="admin" password="{noop}admin" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider  >

    </security:authentication-manager>
```

Ignore the *security:* prefix in the tags.

*{noop}* in front of the password ensures that I am not using any encryption for the password.

**Controller to show login JSP**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "" }, method = { RequestMethod.GET})
    public String login(HttpServletRequest request) {
        System.out.println("LoginController.login() "+request.getRequestURI());
        return "login";
    }

}
```

**Form action**

```
<form name='loginForm' action="login-user" method='POST'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue but not while using spring. We were hosting two instances of our own in house application on the same server but using two different ports. Login to one instance was okay, however login to the other one from the same browser (another tab) caused the error above to be thrown from tomcat, preceded with this message "*CSRF nonce validation failed*".

 The workaround I did is to login to the other instance from different browser. I know that this is not a fix but it may help if you have a situation similar to mine

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you use normal <form> tags with spring security, while it checks for CSRF attacks.

The solution is:

- Add CSRF hidden field with each <form> tag

```html
<form action="..." method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}" value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

- Or use spring MVC <form:form> tags which include this hidden field automtically (Recommended)

```html
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<form:form action="..." method="POST">

</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This also happened with me when I accidentally launched two instances of my application on different tomcat servers.  I resolved it by removing the working directories of the application in my `webapps` and `work` folders, and restarting the server.

Answer (score 0):

use `<form:form>` tags when you're dealing with spring security, instead of manually adding the CSRF token for each forms as below

```
<form:form action="", method="">
</form:form>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case this happen because of the `authorities` setting under `user-service` tag. Removing hasRole works for me.

```
<http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern ="/admin" access = "hasRole('ROLE-USER')"/>
</http>
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
    <user-service>
        <user name = "abc" password = "xyz" authorities="ROLE-USER" />
    </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Better to open the web application in incognito window.